# How does this sed command works?

Tags: sed

How does this sed line works :

```
echo lred_6607: broken symbolic link to ./safaribooks/red_6607 |
sed -e 's/^\|: *broken symbolic.*$/"/g'
```

1.There is no `|` character in the output of previous command.

2.what is the use of `^` and `$`

3.How does the output is prefixed and suffixed by a pair of
        double quotes

output : `"lred_6607"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `sed` line selects sequences of chars and replace them with `"`. The parts of the line which are not matched are left unchanged.

`\|` means **or**, so it separates 2 regexes.

Any sequence of chars matched by these 2 regexes is replaced with `"`.

The first is `^`. It matches the start of the line.
If start of the line is encountered, it is replaced with `"`

The second regex is `: *broken symbolic.*$`: it means any string starting with `:` and zero or any number of space chars (`*`), and `broken symbolic` char sequence, and followed with `.*` which means zero or any number of any chars, up to the end of line `$`. If encountered it is replaced with `"`.

`lred_6607` is not matched at all, so it is left unchanged.

The result is `"lred_6607"`